# Opening another activity using Firebase UI RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I looked at several answers to this topic but none produced the desired result I want to have. I have an RecyclerView using the Firebase UI for RecyclerView where I want to add a OnClick event. So the user clicks on an item in the RecyclerView and gets to another activity. For this I am using an intent in my adapter class but somehow it is not working, if I click on an item of the RecyclerView nothings happens, it should open the next activity but it doesn't. Is there another way to open another activity?

Here is my adapter class:

```
class UserHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewUsername;

        public UserHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewUsername = itemView.findViewById(R.id.player_name_search);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null){
                        listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position),(position));
                        Intent i = new Intent (itemView.getContext(), FriendRequest.class);
                        itemView.getContext().startActivity(i);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }
```

Here is the activity where I use the onItemClickListener:

```
userAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new UserAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
                Intent i = new Intent(PlayerSearch.this, FriendRequest.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Here is my list_item layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        style="@style/CardViewWidgets"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/picture_prize_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/suezkanal"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/listitem_text_view_prize_game"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal_size"
                android:text="Some text"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                style="@style/TextView"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain exactly what "not working" means.

Comment: If I click on an item in RecyclerView, it does not open the next activity, it does nothing

Comment: Is your activity declared in Manifest properly?

Comment: Yes both activities are declared in the manifest properly

Comment: Is your `itemView`'s `OnClickListener` running? Have you tried putting a log print it breakpoint there? What's in the item layout, exactly? Anything that might be interfering with a click on the whole `View`; e.g., a `Button`, a `CheckBox`, etc.?

Comment: I added my list_item layout file, but there seems no problem with it

Comment: Remove the `android:clickable` and `android:focusable` attributes from the `<CardView>`. Or get rid of the outer `LinearLayout`, since it's rather pointless.

Comment: Yes, removing the outer LinearLayout was the solution, thank you. I kept the attributes in the CardView

Comment: When you are making an answer below I can accept it and close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer of @Mike M. this problem has been resolved. I had to delete my outer LinearLayout of the ListItem:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        style="@style/CardViewWidgets"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/picture_prize_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/suezkanal"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/listitem_text_view_prize_game"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal_size"
                android:text="Some text"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                style="@style/TextView"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```